# When upstream common ancestor is merge commit, rebasing includes it's ancestor in the rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am a little confused. I had a git history as follows (* means a merge commit):

```
A - B - C* - D - E - F* (master) - H* - I - J - K (feature)
         \                       /
          \- - - - - - - - - - G
```

I then ran `git rebase -i master feature`, and in the todo list put an `r` in front of commit `G` to preserve it (while changing the commit message), and an `s` in front of everything else to squash it all together. I expected to get this:

```
                       Y (feature), containing G', H', I', J', K'
                      / 
A - B - C* - D - E - F* (master)
```

Instead I got this:

```
                   X (feature), containing F`?, G', H', I', J', K'
                  /
A - B - C* - D - E - F* (master)
```

I think X contains `F'` as well as `G' - K'`, since it has changes from that merge and because the rebase gave it the same author as `F'`, an author which only shows up on `X`, `D`, and `F*`.

What went wrong here? Is this because git rebase ignores merge commits, therefore it won't accept a merge commit as the common ancestor of the `<upstream>` and `<branch>` arguments? Running `git log master..K` only shows commits `G - K`.

What is the correct way to avoid this? I have read elsewhere that the `-i` and `-p` flags can't be used simultaneously.

**UPDATE:**

For what it's worth, I've included a screenshot of my `git log` graph. going backwards in time, the green and yellow lines eventually join and earlier on the pink line joins.

[image]

Comment: Your attempt to rebase-and-squash sounds right to me, so I'm not sure what went wrong. Meanwhile, though, you say that `*` indicates a merge commit, but in your graph, commit `F` (`master`) has only one parent `E`, which makes it not-a-merge-commit. (The same holds for `C`.) This doesn't bear directly on the issue, but it makes me wonder if there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to simplify it, but I've posted the full thing if it's worth anything.

Comment: Hm, this is even odder, because the commit you labeled `feature_after` is a merge commit (parents `a21f9...` and `0e1...`) and unless you use `-p`, `git rebase -i` doesn't make merges. (If you do combine `-i` and `-p` you get weirdness.)

Comment: yeah, i just double checked my history and it was definitely `git rebase -i master feature`. Idk, maybe it's a bug. I'm on version `2.14.3 (Apple Git-98)`. Someone suggested I try to merge in `G` (or `d56...`) by itself first and then do the rebase squash, so I'm going to try that.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest git and I got the same behavior.

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by merging `G` in first separately, as mentioned, but it would be nice to know why this behavior was occurring.